# how to pass retro function parameter in next Activity

Tags: android

how to pass retro function parameter in next acitivity.

```
public void retro(Context mContext,String mId){
  // context=mContext;
    final SubInterfaceActivity apiService =
            SubApiActivity.getClient().create(SubInterfaceActivity.class);
    Call<ResponseListSubClassification> call =  apiService.subclassificationList("84",mId);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseListSubClassification>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseListSubClassification> call,  Response<ResponseListSubClassification> response) {

            final List<DataListSubClassification> ret =  response.body().getData();

            Log.d(TAG, "Number of item received: " + ret.size());
            adapter = new SubListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), ret);
            setListAdapter(adapter);
            listView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
            //   final CheckBox checkBox=(CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(final AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {

                    final DataListSubClassification countr =  (DataListSubClassification) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Clicked on Row: " + countr.getID(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    int images=position;
                    Intent intent= new Intent(SubClassificationActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("",images);

                    //  Object obj = adapter.getItem(position);
```

//                        Intent r = new   Intent(SubClassificationActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    Intent(SubClassificationActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
    parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

```
                    ImageView checkBox;
                    if(preview !=null) {
                        checkBox=  (ImageView)  preview.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
                        checkBox.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                    }
                    checkBox = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
                    checkBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    preview=view;
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: To pass data to next Activity, you can use Intent Extra or Bundle. If you pass data using intent.putExtra(), then you can get that intent using 'getIntent()'. Also your question is not proper, please write proper details don't copy past code.